# How to format data so that it can be stored in a mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store some data in a mysql database through a php script. The data that I am trying to store is encrypted and so this means that it stores something like this:

```
'$ñŠN4Åßv4ñ•ÜÅØµÙÜqÚö4Þ§ƒÑìèêù¬a+µºeN¶†)‰ož¥´™³¯BâPqt‡š3ÊØyGyŠí!¬‚ƒý`,È-SFn­…,˜EïÕ¬_¯ ÛÆ1y©aœ«#˜¼öe÷·2,¢‹éUËx‰0ý`ÎªÄÅŒ1²ljìí -{6“6{ÊÜ¤^3ùˆ-G¹'
```

However, when I try to construct my query, I get an error connecting to the database as these encrypted values sometimes have quotation marks (' or ") and commas meaning that the query is wrongly interpreted.

Is there a way that I can ignore the commas and quotes in this data so that my query is properly interpreted and so a value like the one above can be stored?

Many Thanks.

(My query works when I simply put in plaintext and no encrypted data)

Comment: The basics in every introduction about using sql queries explain about "escaping". Take a look at that again...

Comment: Use prepared statements, then there's no problems with quotes in the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do a mysql escape which escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement.

Eg..

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$encrypted = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $encryptedText);

$sql="INSERT INTO table (columnName) VALUES ($encrypted)";

mysqli_query($con,$sql);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking if that is how your data looks, you could declare the data type of your table's column to be a blob then if you are using PHP you could use pdo functions to do CRUD in your MySQL database. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared statements is the best way to go in my opinion but you should learn about escaping too, it is something you should know.

Prepared statements are easy, basically

```
SELECT something FROM somewhere WHERE this = :that

bind('that', $val)
```

You should look into PDO, this will help https://phpdelusions.net/pdo